# Exclude 0 from !value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a variant of the following code, but would like when `stdin == 0` to continue with the prompts and break only on every other `!value` case.

So far I have managed to make it work when stdin is a string (no unary +) and with `Number(value)` converting at the end.

The problem with my checks is that both zero and !value convert to false, which is the standard case afaik. I have tried with AND, OR operators but with no luck.

```js
let sum = 0;

while(true) {
  
  let value = +prompt('Choose value:','');

  if ( !value ) break;
  
  sum += value;
}
```

Comment: *“I have tried with AND, OR operators but with no luck.”* How did you try these?

Comment: Basically,I have tried all sorts of variants similar to @31piy suggestion `value !== 0 && !value` but they created an infinite loop on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is a number, and the only falsy numbers are 0 and NaN. You can check for NaN directly:

```
if (isNaN(value)) break;
```

Keep in mind that `+''` is 0 and not NaN, however. It might be more appropriate to save the cast for later. There’s even the option of applying stricter validation, ruling out inputs like `Infinity` or `1.2e3`:

```js
let sum = 0;

while (true) {
    const input = prompt('Choose value:');
    const value = Number(input);

    if (isNaN(value) || input === null || input.trim() === '') {
        break;
    }

    sum += value;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! I reckon there is no way to get Cancel to work as well since it outputs 0.

Comment: @csgeneralist: I’ve edited in a snippet that shows how you can distinguish empty strings from 0.

Comment: This is top-notch, thank you! Excludes 0 but includes Cancel :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check directly if the value equals to zero:

```js
let sum = 0;

while(true) {
  let value = +prompt('Choose value:','');
  if ( value !== 0 && !value ) break;
  sum += value;
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a default value of `NaN` for getting an empty string `''` before converting to number.

Then check if the value is not a number and break the loop.

```js
let sum = 0;

while(true) {
    let value = +(prompt('Choose value:').trim() || NaN);
    if (isNaN(value)) break;
    sum += value;
}

console.log(sum);
```